# Inverse Mellin Transform

Tags: integral-transforms, inverse-laplace

We all know that the Inverse Mellin Transform is
$$\left\{\mathcal{M}^{-1}\varphi\right\}(x) = f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} x^{-s} \varphi(s)\, \mathrm{d}s.$$
So what is my problem? I want to calculate an integral, which looks like:
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} x^{s} \varphi(s)\, \mathrm{d}s$$
I want to express this integral as a Inverse Mellin Transformation. My idea was to do a small substitution, so that $s \rightarrow -s$. But then the integral has different boundaries:
$$-\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{-c+i \infty}^{-c-i \infty} x^{-s} \varphi(s)\, \mathrm{d}s = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{-c-i \infty}^{-c+i \infty} x^{-s} \varphi(s)\, \mathrm{d}s$$
This is an Inverse Mellin Transform but $c\rightarrow-c$. How can I get to a real Inverse Mellin Transform?

Comment: Depending on your context, you might have to hope that $\ph$ is meromorphic on the strip $-c\le \Re(s) \le c$, with suitable bounds, so you can move the contour back...